# Getting an object into a ChannelBuffer

Tags: java, http, netty

I've written a small http server using Netty by following the [example http server](http://static.netty.io/3.5/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/http/file/package-summary.html) and now i'm trying to adapt it to my needs (a small app that should send json). I began by manually encoding my POJOs to json using jackson and then using the StringEncoder to get a ChannelBuffer. Now i'm trying to generalize it slightly by extracting the bit that encodes the POJOs to json by adding a [HttpContentEncoder](http://static.netty.io/3.5/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpContentEncoder.html) and I've managed to implement that more or less.

The part that i can't figure out is how to set the content on the [HttpResponse](http://static.netty.io/3.5/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpResponse.html). It expects a ChannelBuffer but how do i get my object into a ChannelBuffer?

**Edit**

Say i have a handler with code like below and have a HttpContentEncoder that knows how to serialize SomeSerializableObject. Then how do i get my content (SomeSerializableObject) to the HttpContentEncoder? That's what i'm looking for.

```
SomeSerializableObject obj = ...

// This won't work becuase the HttpMessage expects a ChannelBuffer
HttpRequest res = ...
res.setContent(obj);

Channel ch = ...
ch.write(res);
```

After looking into it a bit more though i'm unsure if this is what HttpContentEncoder is meant to do or rather do stuff like compression?

Answer (score 3):

Most object serialization/deserialization libraries use `InputStream` and `OutputStream`.  You could create a dynamic buffer (or a wrapped buffer for deserialization), wrap it with `ChannelBufferOutputStream` (or `ChannelBufferInputStream`) to feed the serialization library.  For example:

```
// Deserialization
HttpMessage m = ...;
ChannelBuffer content = m.getContent();
InputStream in = new ChannelBufferInputStream(content);
Object contentObject = myDeserializer.decode(in);

// Serialization
HttpMessage m = ...;
Object contentObject = ...;
ChannelBuffer content = ChannelBuffers.dynamicBuffer();
OutputStream out = new ChannelBufferOutputStream(content);
mySerializer.encode(contentObject, out);
m.setContent(content);
```

If the serialization library allows you to use a byte array instead of streams, this can be much simpler using `ChannelBuffer.array()` and `ChannelBuffer.arrayOffset()`.

Comment: yeah, that's a nice way to serialize it but not what i'm looking for.